# how to config container with request variable

Tags: service, containers, symfony

In the first place I had to configure parameters using the class "ParametersCompilerPass" to get data from database.Here si my class :

```
class ParametersCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {


    $em = $container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');

    $boutique = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Boutique')->findOneByNom($container->getParameter('boutique.config'));

       if(null !== $boutique){
            $container->setParameter('url_site', $boutique->getUrl());
            $container->setParameter('idboutique', $boutique->getId());
       }else{
            $container->setParameter('url_site', null);
            $container->setParameter('idboutique', 0);

        }


   }
}
```

and when i set a parameter from request, it dont work, i tried in adding this code :

```
    $request = $container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();


    if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){

        if (null !== $choixbout = $request->get('choixbout')){

           // $this->container->setParameter('idboutique',$choixbout);

        }

     }
```

the service request_stack return null.

I do not know how to configure a parameter from a POST variable.

Hope you can help me.
thanks

Comment: Basically, you can't do request based configuration.  The whole point of the Symfony configuration process is to compile everything into one big optimized cache and use it for all requests.  Take a look at kernel listeners and see if they meet your requirements.

Comment: i tried to use the kernel.request listener but i get this error :"Impossible to call set() on a frozen ParameterBag".so i can 't configure parameter after that DIC has been compiled.i am blocked

Comment: Correct.  Parameters are part of the frozen compiled cache.  Typically, your listener might add additional parameters to the request object for use downstream.

Answer (score 0):

Is it solid requirement to have the parameter set?

It could be handy to create a service which has a request dependency that can act as a `boutique` parameter holder.

For example

```
# app/config/services.yml
app.boutique:
    class: AppBundle\Boutique\Boutique
    arguments: ['@request_stack']

app.boutique_info_dependant1:
    class: AppBundle\Boutique\BoutiqueDependant1
    arguments: ['@app.boutique']

app.boutique_info_dependant2:
    class: AppBundle\Boutique\BoutiqueDependant2
    arguments: ['@app.boutique']
```

This would be a parameter handler.

```
# AppBundle/Boutique/Boutique.php
class Boutique
{
    /** @var RequestStack */
    private $requestStack;

    /**
     * BoutiqueListener constructor.
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function getBoutique()
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        /// here you can add an extra check if the request is master etc.

        if ($request->getMethod() == Request::METHOD_POST) {
            if (null !== $choixbout = $request->get('choixbout')) {
                return $choixbout;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then using the handler

```
class BoutiqueDependant1
{
    public function __construct(Boutique $boutique)
    {
        $this->myBoutique = $boutique->getBoutique();
    }
}
```

This does not look like the best solution but could work...
Other option would be to rethink the application architecture to handle boutique information somehow differently.